# problems opening horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with part of the html and css code

I am working on a menu that has children. Unfortunately, this child cannot be opened by holding the mouse over it. I have put the html & css code inside the website site so that friends can give a proper guide.

```
[https://codepen.io/croner2/pen/vYRrpMg][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code was missing, where we make the dropdown `ul` tag visible on hover!

```css
#mainNavigation nav.desktop ul li.dropdown:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/kai1992cool/pen/qBoKxbN)

Comment: i have problem on mobile version please check menu mobile version